# Doctrine 2 Association Mapping (ManyToOne and OneToMany)

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am new with Doctrine2 and need some help.
I have 2 Entities: LocationEntity and RatingEntity
**RatingEntity**

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Rating
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="`RATING`")
 */
class RatingEntity {

    /**
     *
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="`ID`", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="RATING_ID_SEQ", initialValue=1, allocationSize=1)
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     *
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(name="`LOCATION_ID`", type="integer")
     */
    protected $locationId;

    /**
     * @var LocationEntity
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="LocationEntity", inversedBy="ratings")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="`LOCATION_ID`", referencedColumnName="`ID`")
     */
    protected $location;

    /**
     * @return the $location
     */
    public function getLocation() {
        return $this->location;
    }

    /**
     * @param field_type $location
     */
    public function setLocation($location) {
        $this->location = $location;
    }
```

and **LocationEntity**

```
<?php       

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;

/**
 * Location
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="`LOCATION`")
 */
class LocationEntity {

    /**
     *
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="`ID`", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="LOCATION_ID_SEQ", initialValue=1, allocationSize=1)
     */
    protected $id;            

    /**
     *
     * @var ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="RatingEntity", mappedBy="location", cascade={"persist"}, fetch="LAZY")
     */
    protected $ratings;

    /**
     * @return the $ratings
     */
    public function getRatings() {

        return $this->ratings;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $ratings
     */
    public function setRatings($ratings) {

        $this->ratings = $ratings;
    }

    /**
     * Never forget to initialize all your collections!
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->ratings = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

If I get locations, i get ratings for location as Array, 
but if I want to get Rating and Location for it, I get NULL only in getLocation().

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you need the locationId property in your Rating entity as the column is already mapped using the location property. Try removing the locationId section and see if it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: This is a part of old code, I change Entity from Fields to Objects. I've tried remove it already. This don't help.